# Django: Regroup tag, order by "count"?

Tags: python, django

How do I order a regrouped set by the number of members in the set?

I'd like to do something like this:

```
{% regroup object.user.followed_by.all|dictsort:"profile_type.name.count" by profile_type.name as follower_list %}
```

...But it doesn't work.

(This article is worth reading as context: http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2013/10/26/django-dictsort-template-tag/ tl;dr "distsort" can be passed methods)

Many thanks!

Comment: I think your question should be :how do I regroup an ordered set, since the filter (dictsort) is applied before the tag (regroup). Are you sure that the "dictsort" works? Could you test it separately?

Comment: dictsort is the recommended method in the Django documentation; regroup doesn't change the order of the list it receives.

Comment: What I meant was that you should only run the dictsort part and see if it does its job and then run the regroup on the result. Maybe something like this http://pastebin.com/mTsL59a1

Comment: Nice! I'm not on that project any more, but that looks like the right solution. Just couldn't think of how to do it.